# Can scrollbars be made visible in Adobe Reader XI?

Tags: windows-8, adobe-reader, display-settings, scrollbar

Due to some reason*, I would need to display vertical and horizontal scrollbar in Adobe Reader XI. (My installed version is 11.0.10.)

I think I checked all preferences and did not find way to turn them on. Is there such a way?

*) Screen grabber needs them for capturing scrolling content.

Comment: On Windows 7 I get both horizontal and vertical scroll bars when they are needed (depends on the zoom level)

Comment: So apparently you have a PDF file and you want to convert it to an image, correct? Why not open the pdf directly with something that converts it to an image for you? For example Adobe Photoshop or XNView?

Comment: @DavidPostill - thank you David. I added [tag:windows-8]

Comment: @LPChip - thank you, but these are paid and current task is not worth buying them. Perhaps I'll find something free, too.

Comment: XNView is not paid.

Comment: @LPChip – **Please don't mislead readers. [XNView costs $26](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnview/#downloads).** It is freeware only for limited use cases, I quote `for private or educational use (including non-profit organizations)`. I think I'm not falling under these conditions.

Comment: Oh. I found the software on portablefreeware.com which only hosts free software. I assumed it was free as it can be found there.

Comment: But if you need something commercially, just ask your boss to pay for a license. Its quite common to pay for this kind of services.

Comment: @LPChip - if I really needed it, I would purchase it. If there's some free way, it would be better. I have no boss, I'm on my own. But my year gross fulltime income is below 11k$, so I need to purchase tools wisely.

Comment: I understand. I'm sure there are such tools available for free too, question is if their license will be for commercial use too. You can try using Foxit Reader and see if your screen grabber picks that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to show classical scroll bars in Adobe Reader XI. It is obvious from behavior that some scrollbars are shown on touch scrolling, so Adobe implemented own ones.

- However, PDF page can be grabbed by zooming appropriately and then using **Capture Tool**.
- If using FoxIt Reader, then scrollbars are visible, but grabbing tool has problem with horizontal scrolling. Still better than nothing.
- There is also way to use ImageMagick, like shown [in this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/11159/2336).